# swagger inspector supports https resources/methods/URL or not

Tags: java, spring, apache, rest, api

Swagger Inspector is an API testing tool. Is this support https:// URL, because in POSTMAN tool for https methods we need to give Certificate. Is swagger inspector used for https:// or not

Comment: In swagger inspector we need not give any certificate like POSTMAN, it simply works without any certificate or SSL or proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.
If you check their website then you will see their test link is https. So i believe they support it.

[Test link](https://inspector.swagger.io/builder?url=https%3A%2F%2Fswapi.co%2Fapi%2Fpeople)